# Why is my image not displaying and how could I increase the room given also my animations don't work as well

Tags: css, styling

[Project Link](https://codepen.io/_Unkown/pen/qBrprdm)

I'm trying to get my background image to be visible but it doesn't appear, Also my css animations don't work as well any information on how to correct this?

```css
.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/Hn0vxz91/Bridge.jpg");

  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid 1px red;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
body{
  background-color:#28282B;
}

/* Style the links inside the pill navigation menu */
.pill-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Change the color of links on mouse-over */
.pill-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.pill-nav a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

pulse a:hover{ 
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;   
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.1);
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
  }
}
/* Style the container with a rounded border, grey background and some padding and margin */
.container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

/* Clear floats after containers */
.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Float images inside the container to the left. Add a right margin, and style the image as a circle */
.container img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Increase the font-size of a span element */
.container span {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness. This will center both the text and the image inside the container */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .container img {
    margin: auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}


.checked {
  color: orange;
}

  
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  
  
}

.title {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 18px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
}
 
#star{
  background-color:#28282B;
}
.container{
  background-color:#28282B;
}
.center {
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <title> Portfoilo</title>
  <nav id="navbar">
  <div class="pill-nav">
    <div class="pulse">
  <a class="active" href="#welcome-section">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
      <a href="#certifications" class="nav-link">Certifications</a></nav>  </div>
  </div>
  </header>
  
          
          <main><section>
       <div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="bg-text">
  <h1>I Am John Doe</h1>
  <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
</div>
            </section>
           
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <h1 id="practice"> Welcome to My Practice Portfolio</h1></section>
    
    
   <p>This is my practice portfolio to fune tune my skills when I am readyu to showcase my skills to the web I will link it to the actual one when it's ready and I am ready to share on the web thank you for reading this messgae.</p>
 <section id="projects">
   <a href="https://codepen.io/_Unkown/pen/poeNypP"  class="project-tile">Tribute Page</a>
   <a href="https://codepen.io/_Unkown/pen/dyvVKpy" class="project-tile"> Technical Documentation</a>
            </section>
            
    <section id="Certifications">
      <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/fccd07383cd-e15a-40e6-8c7b-ef77282dc751" id="profile-link" target="_blank">Certifications</a></section>
  </main>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/21/45/47/2145477174ea52cd79758af817b905b9.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:90px">
  <p><span>Julie Jacobs.</span> CEO at Mighty Schools.</p>
  <p>John Doe saved us from a web disaster.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.byrdie.com/thmb/fLsxKLnkeZWgt54cWlUCw8ya1KE=/1716x1716/smart/filters:no_upscale()/Screen-Shot-2020-08-31-at-2.57.48-PM-ab7152b68d9042838d10c0ff58f8d3bf.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:90px">
  <p><span >Rebecca Flex.</span> CEO at Company.</p>
  <p>No one is better than John Doe</p>
  <div id="star">
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
  
  <footer>
    <!-- Add icon library -->


<div class="card">
  <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/9bb29e1304526b5aeb6378f485f16bd5310dff9e/0_236_4500_2700/master/4500.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=b87889efa83846281e306c50ef9370db" alt="John" style="width:100%">
  <h1 class="contact">John Doe</h1>
  <p class="title">CEO & Founder, Example</p>
  <p>Harvard University</p>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <p><button>Contact</button></p>
</div>
    </footer>
```

I'm trying to get my image to display while having a shade of the background color add effect to the image and I have css animations that don't work any information on how to fix all that? So they both could become visible also the card section how to make one portion of it white.

Comment: Got ,y image to appear not as I would liked but it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is working fine for me right now.

About the animation; You mean `div class pulse` right?

Put `<nav>` inside `<body>` and see if it works or not.